# .htaccess Get Parameters to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I redirect every request to index.php?
I also want the first 5 parameters as Get values.

Etc. /foo/bar/melon/car/berry/ would request index.php/?one=foo&two=bar&three=melon&four=car&five=berry (if only /foo/bar/ three, four and five would be empty etc.)

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3&four=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3&four=$4&five=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you.
Do you how I can make exceptions? Eg. /404/, should just request 404.php

Comment: You can add those specific rules just below RewriteBase line.